# Android Error: Code undefined, Message Undefined

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to execute the [phoneGap's media example](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media) but it's giving such error. When i click on the given link it suppose to play a mp3 file but it gives error. Why so?

Someone has any idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem as well but noticed that it worked if you reference a full url to a sound on the internet, Using the sample url rockGuitar.mp3">http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s-_rockGuitar.mp3 works for me.

```
    function clickSound() {
        alert("Sound");
        playAudio("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To address a local file use

```
    function clickSound() {
    alert("Sound");
        playAudio("/android_asset/www/foo.mp3");
    }
```

This works for me.

Comment: "/android_asset" refers to the assets folder. then the subdirectories and the file. so if the file is in assets/xx/yy.mp3 the url should be "/android_asset/xx/yy.mp3".